# Strange behavior of Luis.ai

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

In my Luis app i have an intent "goodbyeIntent" with examples "goodbye", "thanks" and "ciao". There is another intent containing lots of examples and, of course, the None-intent.

When i test the app i get the following predictions:
goodbye: 0.97 (goodbyeIntent)
ciao: 0.97 (goodbyeIntent)
thanks: 0.97 (goodbyeIntent)

Although i would have expected scores of 1.00 these results seems to be ok.

Now when i test the app with a word or sentence that is different from all examples of goodbyeIntent, let's say "this is a test", luis nevertheless predicts goodbyIntent with a very high score.

In this case i would have expected the None-Intent to be predicted.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Do you have only "goodbye", "thanks" and "ciao" utterances for intent "goodbyeIntent"?

Comment: There are some variations of these three. But none longer than 3 words.

Comment: Oh no ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-intent My None-intent IS empty and so luis "forces an utterance that is outside the domain into one of the domain intents". I've read alot but must have missed this somehow ...

Comment: Other few tips: yes, ensure that your None intent has some samples of what should not be taken into account, but also avoid mixing languages in your project (here goodbye is EN, ciao is IT): you should always use the language defined for your project in the utterances

Comment: Are you able to share export of your LUIS application?